# ログメッセージをSyslogサーバーに転送したい

Tags: linux, security

ログを出力するプログラムが複数あり、ログへの出力は Syslog を使っておらず普通のテキストファイルに結果を追記しています。これらのログファイルを Syslogサーバーに転送するにはどうしたら良いでしょうか。

プログラムはそれぞれ次の言語で組まれています。

- Java
- Perl
- Ruby

サーバー環境は CentOS6, 7, RHEL6 が混在していて それぞれのローカルディスク上に出力しています。以下は例ですが 物理、仮想合わせて50台くらいです。

> （例)
>
> - CentOS6: `/var/log/application.log`
> - CentOS7: `/var/log/appname/system.log`
> - RHEL6: `/opt/app/logs/error.log`

Syslogサーバーは RHEL6 で `Syslog-ng` が動いています。

*追記*

また、各ログファイルは出力するプログラムの書式で、エラー、デバッグ、ワーニングが出力されているので ローカルログ毎に 条件を指定できて Error, Warning, Debug, Info レベルで Syslog出力できるのが理想です。

Comment: 後出しですみませんが、ログ転送だけでなくエラーレベルも制御できる必要があると気がついたので 質問に追記しました。

Comment: このような用途では真っ先に [Fluentd](http://www.fluentd.org/) の利用を思いつくのですが、要件なり機能なりの観点から使えなかったということなんでしょうか。

Comment: 既存のSyslogサーバーにログを集めたいという要件でしたが Fluentd から Syslog出力させる方法がわからず 考慮から外してました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sec](http://simple-evcorr.github.io/)でログファイルを読み込んで、正規表現などでフィルターして logger に渡す方法が考えられます。

```
[/etc/sec/application-log.rules]
type=Single
ptype=RegExp
pattern=(正規表現)
desc=application.log Error
action=pipe '$0' /bin/logger -p local1.error

type=Single
ptype=RegExp
pattern=(正規表現)
desc=application.log Warning
action=pipe '$0' /bin/logger -p local1.warning

    :

(コマンド)
    /usr/bin/sec --conf=/etc/sec/application-log.rules --input=/var/log/application.log
```

1行ごとに logger を実行するのは負荷が高いかもしれません。
ログレベルごとにファイルに書き出して "tail -f" + logger" と組み合わせるとか。

```
[/etc/sec/application-log.rules]
type=Single
ptype=RegExp
pattern=(正規表現)
desc=application.log Error
action=write /var/log/application.log.error $0

type=Single
ptype=RegExp
pattern=(正規表現)
desc=application.log Warning
action=write /var/log/application.log.warning $0
    :

(コマンド)
    /usr/bin/sec --conf=/etc/sec/application-log.rules --input=/var/log/application.log
    tail -f /var/log/application.log.error | logger -p local1.error
    tail -f /var/log/application.log.warning | logger -p local1.warning
        :
```

Answer (score 2):

syslogのクライアントからリモートのsyslogの転送ができているとして、ファイルの内容をsyslogに書き込むには

```
logger -f /var/log/application.log
```

または

```
tail -f /var/log/application.log | logger
```

**追記:**

アプリの変更ができない前提で回答を書きましたが、きちんとやるならJava, Perl, Rubyのアプリそれぞれでsyslogに直接書き込むのが当然良いでしょう。Javaならlog4jを使っているでしょうから、propertiesの変更だけでいけるはず。以下設定例。

```
# configure the root logger
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, SYSLOG


# configure Syslog facility LOCAL1 appender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG=org.apache.log4j.net.SyslogAppender
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.syslogHost=localhost
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.facility=LOCAL4
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.SYSLOG.layout.conversionPattern=[%p] %c:%L - %m%n
```

Perl, Rubyも同様にロガーモジュールを使っているなら設定があるはずです。Pythonでも標準のloggingモジュールでsyslogに書き込めます。

**蛇足**

ところでsyslogの実装のうちrsyslogdはお勧めしません。ローカルのrsyslogに書き込むとリモートのsyslogがダウンしているときに、ローカルのファイルシステムに一時保存してくれるとか,SSL/TLSが使えるのが魅力なのですが、何らかのバグがあって高負荷時にハングアップします。

Comment: 試してみました。 facilityとレベルが logger に指定した内容で統一されてしまいますが結果としては出来ました。当初はファイル転送さえ出来れば良いと思ってましたが エラーとファシリティを制御する必要があるんだなと考えもまとまりました。

Answer (score 1):

自己レスですが、syslog-ng では `source` の設定に `file()` driver を設定するとローカルファイルを読み込めるようです。

[6.3.2. file() source options - - The syslog-ng Open Source Edition 3.7 Administrator Guide](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-latest-guides/en/syslog-ng-ose-guide-admin/html/reference-source-file.html)